# Dealing with different number of levels in train and test data sets

Tags: r

My knowledge in this area is poor, so apologize me if this is a trivial question.

I need to train a model and I have two data sets: Train data for building the model and a Scoring data to apply the model on it.

One important categorical variable has 200 level in Train data and it has only 50 levels in the scoring data. In fact they only share 20 levels.

So, what is the correct way to deal with such situation? should I limit the levels to the intersect of the levels or keep it as it or what? 
Bests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of different options here.  I assume you are talking about a single attribute here and i'm also assuming since you are talking about a level it is numerical:

1. The first option is to do nothing and to see what result you get.
2. The second is to normalize the values.  Setting them all on the same scale accordingly from 0to1.
3. You could also try binning, I'm not sure what that is in R.

I'm not an expert but I've found doing some testing and trying different methods doesn't hurt.  A program I use with school is called Weka it's free and opened source plus there are instructional videos that will introduce you to the theory behind data analysis
http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/index.html

Comment: Pretty sure they're talking about a categorical var, not continuous. I could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

When using your test dataset to test your model, you will need to filter-out the levels that are not present in your test dataset (assuming your model cannot handle missing levels).

Alternatively, you could re-partition your data into a test and training sets where all of the levels in the test set are present in the training set. The `createDataParition` function from the `caret` package will do this for you - e.g. see [here](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-71/topics/createDataPartition).